# UITableViewAutomaticDimension, get the same height if detailTextLabel text is nil

Tags: ios, uikit

I am using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` with cells with Subtitle style.

When there is no text on detailTextLabel those rows appear to be smaller which is expected to happen by default.

However as this is not desirable, what would be the way to override that, aside from using the Custom Cell?

I've heard about setting the height constrain (in this particular case it would need to be set in the code), but I haven't succeeded in doing that.

Comment: Don't try to mess with the built-in tableview cells. Use a custom cell. A two-label (title + detail) cell is such a trivial thing, that's a much better route to go.

Comment: Your other option... if there is no text for the `detailTextLabel` set it to " " (a space). That way it will not show anything, but the field will still be there taking up the vertical space.

Comment: @DonMag the text wlil not be centered so that is not the option unfortunately, I was aware of that.

Comment: Could you be more accurate about your needs because you may want to deal with the Dynamic Type feature according to the comments you wrote in an answer and it's never mentioned in your post, please?

Comment: @XLE_22 the question is accurate. I need UITableViewAutomaticDimension with cells with Subtitle style to have minimal height. Technically it should be possible though it may be complicated that's another thing. I have mentioned Dynamic Type only because someone insisted on alternative solution and it doesn't work because of that. I don't need/already know/haven't asked for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to have all row heights be the same, with the `textLabel` centered vertically when there is no text for the `detailTextLabel`, you can accomplish this with the default `Subtitle` cell by adding this line in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 56
```

---

**Edit**

That option is not compatible with Dynamic Type -- this throws a bit of a wrench into the task.

One approach - which is kind of a work-around, but will do the job:

- Custom cell
- Start by laying it out with proper constraints to (closely) match the default Subtitle cell
- Duplicate the "Title" label
- Constrain that duplicate label vertically centered in the cell

Then, if your data ***does*** have subtitle text, show the title and subtitle labels and hide the "duplicate" title label.

If your data ***does NOT*** have subtitle text, hide the title and subtitle labels and show the "duplicate" title label.

Here is a simple example you can try:

```
class MySubtitleCell: UITableViewCell {

    let myTextLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        return v
    }()

    let myCenteredTextLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        return v
    }()

    let myDetailTextLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
        return v
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.addSubview(myTextLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(myCenteredTextLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(myDetailTextLabel)

        let g = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            myTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 7.0),
            myTextLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            myDetailTextLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myTextLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myDetailTextLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myDetailTextLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -7.0),

            myCenteredTextLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            myCenteredTextLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor, constant: 0.0),

        ])

        // during development, un-comment this block
        // to give labels background colors so we can see their frames
        /*
        myTextLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        myDetailTextLabel.backgroundColor = .green
        myCenteredTextLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        */

    }

}

class DetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(MySubtitleCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MySTCell")
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var detailStr = "The detail text string"

        // set detailStr empty for every-other row
        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            // set it to a space char " " instead of "" to maintain label frame
            detailStr = " "
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MySTCell", for: indexPath) as! MySubtitleCell

        // set same text for myTextLabel and myCenteredTextLabel
        cell.myTextLabel.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
        cell.myCenteredTextLabel.text = cell.myTextLabel.text

        // set myDetailTextLabel
        cell.myDetailTextLabel.text = detailStr

        // if detailStr is not empty (" ")
        //  hide myTextLabel and myDetailTextLabel and show myCenteredTextLabel
        // else
        // show myTextLabel and myDetailTextLabel and hide myCenteredTextLabel

        cell.myTextLabel.isHidden = (detailStr == " ")
        cell.myDetailTextLabel.isHidden = cell.myTextLabel.isHidden
        cell.myCenteredTextLabel.isHidden = !cell.myTextLabel.isHidden

        return cell

    }

}
```

The results (every-other row has no detail label text)...

With "default" font sizes:

[image]

and the same screen, with Larger Fonts via Accessibility / Dynamic Type:

[image]

Comment: It needs to be set to UITableViewAutomaticDimension to be compatible with Dynamic Type, I believe it is mentioned above. Actually whole the problem started with that request, before that it worked exactly like what you have suggested.

Comment: @IvanIčin - ah... didn't notice you needed to accommodate Dynamic Type. See my edited answer.

Comment: @IvanIčin The question never mentions dynamic type.

Comment: @matt no, but the question is clear what it needs and that I don't want alternative solutions. I appreciate that someone took effort for a long answer above, but my project is more complex and this can't be used directly. Dynamic Type was only answer why one particular alternative that was offered can't work and why I insist on exactly what I have asked (if possible) and not on alternatives.

Comment: @IvanIčin = *"my project is more complex"* ... if your project is too complex to use a custom cell, it sounds like it would be ***more*** complex to try and modify the default implementation of a `SubTitle` cell... even if you *could* find a way to modify it to give you the result you want.

Comment: @DonMag, as said the app is working with SubTitle cell already, whether it is too complex or not it is another question. And don't get me wrong but I have the right to ask if it is possible to add some constrain so that the height is always at some minimal. There is no technical reasons why it would be impossible and it might be even very simple code required, just it is the question if someone knows that.

Comment: @IvanIčin - start with a default `SubTitle` cell... run the app... use `Debug View Hierarchy` to inspect the cells - label heights and top & bottom spacing. Switch to Settings app and change the Dynamic Type font-size... Switch back to your app and inspect the cells / label heights / spacing. I think you'll quickly see that there is no "simple code" that will change the cell layout to accomplish your design requirements. However... I suppose there is nothing wrong with hoping someone else will come along with your desired solution.